# How to output matrix/ndarray to a file preserving rows/columns format

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to save a dataset consisting of 2610 rows and 3 columns. The dataset is in the form of a 2610x3 matrix in the script but when I'm using the .tofile() method the file which I'm saving to, doesn't preserve the table/matrix structure but has the values saved in series.

Is there a way to save to a file preserving the ROWSxCOLS format of a matrix/ndarray?

Comment: Have you tried `savetxt`?

Comment: I did just now and it does preserve the RxC format. If you answer the question, I'll select it as the resolution.